# ILoggingBuilder - clear some providers?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, blazor-server-side, azure-application-insights, ilogger

I have a Blazor server web app running on Azure app services. When my code starts, as suggested, I have the following:

```
if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
    builder.Logging.AddJsonConsole();
    builder.Logging.AddDebug();
}
```

Now for production on an Azure app service, please correct me if I'm wrong, as I change nothing it'll set up the following providers (assuming I don't make any calls) - **is this correct?**

- Console
- Debug
- EventSource
- EventLog (Windows only)

And that feeds them across with all the {name} key:values and scopes passed to be displayed as desired - **correct?**

**Question:** Where does the Console & Debug providers go in production on Azure app service? I believe the Console goes nowhere unless I turn app logging on (max 12 hours). Is that correct? And where does Debug go?

**Question:** When I turn on log to the stream in Azure and set it to verbose/debug, it ignores the configuration I set in the appsettings.json and is giving me debug level log output for namespaces I set to warning. Shouldn't appsettings.json stop those log statements from ever getting to Azure?

**Question:** Is the following the correct way to add in Application Insights?

```
if (useApplicationInsights)
{
    builder.Logging.AddApplicationInsights();
    builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Where does the Console & Debug providers go in production on Azure app service?

Yes.the Debug logging provider is designed for local development and debugging purposes. When running your application in a local development environment with a debugger attached (e.g., in Visual Studio), you can see the Debug log messages in the Output window.

> When I turn on log to the stream in Azure and set it to verbose/debug, it ignores the configuration I set in the appsettings.json and is giving me debug level log output

Yes, you are correct. When you enable log streaming in Azure App Service and set the log level to “Verbose” or “Debug,” it will override the log level configurations defined in your appsettings.json file.

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "ConnectionString": "InstrumentationKey=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx;IngestionEndpoint=https://eastus-8.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://eastus.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/"
  }
}
```

Place your InstrumentationKey in place of “xxx” in ConnectionString.

[image]

[image]

> the following the correct way to add in Application Insights?

Yes, the way you have configured is correct.

When deploying a Blazor Server app to Azure App Service, the application will have various logging providers available by default. These providers include Console, Debug, EventSource, and EventLog (Windows only).

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/logging?view=aspnetcore-7.0